# MySQL error or data corruption after database migration

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, taxonomy, mysql

I migrated my database to a new host, as well as my WordPress files, I have an online shop using WooCommerce, and everything ran smoothly after migration, what I did not notice at first was that WooCommerce categories are no longer displayed in the admin panel, When I visit: `/wp-admin/edit-tags.php?taxonomy=product_cat&post_type=product` it gives me two pages, and says 26 items, but nothing is displayed in the list.

I reviewed the error log and found a few queries that should be related to this issue for example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*, tt.* FROM wp_terms AS t  LEFT JOIN wp_termmeta ON ( t.term_id = wp_termmeta.term_id AND wp_termmeta.meta_key='order') INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt ON t.term_id = tt.term_id WHERE tt.taxonomy IN ('product_cat') AND (   ( wp_termmeta.meta_key = 'order' OR wp_termmeta.meta_key IS NULL )) ORDER BY wp_termmeta.meta_value+0 ASC, t.name ASC
```

And when I run this query, MySQL says:

```
#3065 - Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'as7ab_db.wp_termmeta.meta_value' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT
```

I updated WooCommerce to the latest version,  but the problem is still present.

Comment: Apparently the order by clause is messing the whole thing up, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug with WordPress, it's still incompatible with MySQL 8, a quick patch could be found at this link:

https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/48377